# Can GT 710 bottleneck core i5 2120?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, performance

Decided to use my two monitors over a GT 710 instead of Intel HD graphics built into my core i5 2120 processor but there is just one problem, the quality of video improved overall but the card makes my PC hang when doing regular functions such as searching for files or when starting Pycharm or Intellij. Am really afraid to overclock a card without being instructed to do so by manufacturer, so is it possible that the card may be causing the bottleneck because system was faster on Intel HD graphics with poor video quality and how can I calculate the bottleneck extent ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
If you have anything better than a Core 2 (Duo/Quad) then a GT 710 can bottleneck it.
And a Core i5 is better than a Core 2.

Maybe get a GT 1030 instead.
It’s also a low end card.
But has about 4X performance compared to GT 710.

I think GeForce 700 series cards are the last to have drivers for Windows XP though.
But if you’re running Windows 7 or newer, then GT 1030 should work better than GT 710.

GT 1030 also supports 4K 60Hz over HDMI.
It’s too slow to play games at 4K. But it can be used in Windows (or Linux) for regular programs.

Comment: This graphic card burned my MOBO two years ago, I posted here but sadly a motherboard shot is a signal to buy a new one